# ping cmd shows: connect network is unreachable but unable to capture any ICMP packets

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, icmp

I was doing network experiment and now got a trouble. I was using wireshark to capture packets. I can get two ICMP packet for every successful ping cmd but I'm not able to capture anything when ping fails, which I expected to capture a "Destination Unreachable" reply packet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I get this done. I forget to set gateway.